# using Extended WPF toolkit 2.0 in visual studio 2010 framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

i'm trying to incorporate a chart in my WPF app and i cannot build since i get an error `unknown build error, 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly= System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit' mapping URI is not valid`

my xaml file looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="Report_Generator.MainWindow"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        Title="Report Generator" Height="695" Width="961" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
```

and where i've implemented the chart looks like:

```
<my:Chart  Name="ColumnChart1" Title="Total Marks" Margin="33,330,0,358" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="379">
    <my:AreaSeries DependentValuePath="Value"
                   IndependentValuePath="Key"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ColoumnChart1}"
                   IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
</my:Chart>`
```

and code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showColumnChart();
    }

    private void showColumnChart()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> MyValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        MyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Mahak", 300));
        MyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Pihu", 250));
        MyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Rahul", 289));
        MyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Raj", 256));
        MyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Vikas", 140));

        ColumnChart1.DataContext = MyValue;

    }
```

this was a sample code i was trying to implement using the wpftoolkit for framework 3.5 but couldn't build it because of the error. i'm guessing it was due to the framework differences but now i downloaded the extended WPF toolkit 2.0 which i think should run with .NET framework 4.0.does any one know how to go about using the extended WPF toolkit 2.0 with visual stuio 2010 wpf application??? and another issue is that i get an error in the code behind at this point `ColumnChart1.DataContext = MyValue;` saying that the name ColoumnChart1 doesnt exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i got around this issue. turns out there were just a few errors..
in the code behind i added this statement and evrything worked :

`using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;`

ofcourse i had to add the refrences to the wpftoolkit `WPFToolkit` and `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`